# New to php programming <% %> not working?

Tags: php

I am following a tutorial and this code does not work

```
<%

echo "Hello World";

%>
```

While if I try `<? ?>` it does work. I am using XAMPP.

I think its new to php 5. It says which of the followings tags are valid `<? ?> <?= ?> <! !> <% %> <?php ?> <?= ?>`

Comment: `<?php echo "Hello World"; ?>`

Comment: Try `<? ... ?>` or `<?php ... ?>`. These tags depend on the configuration of your php environment.

Comment: If short tag is enabled in php.ini you can use `<?="Hello World"?>` otherwise its `<?php echo "Hello World" ?>`. Always its best option to use normal tag than short tag.

Comment: @Anusha The *echo shortcut* `<?=` no longer depends on short tags. It is always enabled

Answer (score 7):

In PHP there is nothing like `<% %>` by default. You should use instead:

```
<?php

echo "Hello World";

?>
```

`<%` is an ASP syntax. If you really want to use it, you have to enable `asp_tags` but this is a very bad idea in my opinion (compatibility issues, etc).

[Reference](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.asp-tags)

> **asp_tags *boolean***
>
> Enables the use of ASP-like `<% %>` tags in addition to the usual  tags. This includes the variable-value printing shorthand of `<%= $value %>`. For more information, see Escaping from HTML.

Comment: I think its new to php 5. It says which of the followings tags are valid <? ?> <?= ?> <! !> <% %> <?php ?>

Comment: @user3580535 It's not new - `<% %>` is available since PHP 4. However it's disabled by default.

Answer (score 6):

```
 <% %> // asp tags, need asp_tags enabled in php.ini
```

[Source](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php)

I am not sure why the tutorial would use `<% %>`. It is very uncommon, to say the least. Use `<?php ?>` instead.